# std::condition_variable not working with std::this_thread::sleep_for()

Tags: c++, multithreading

Could someone explain why this code does not work as expected when the sleep call in `producer()` is uncommented? It works fine if the sleep call is moved out of the scope of the `unique_lock`.

To clarify:
Working as expected: `producer()` creates new messages that are stored in `data` those messages are then printed by `consumer()`.
What happens when the sleep call is uncommented: no output is produced. I would expect new messages to be produced and printed at 1 second intervals.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <ratio>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <queue>

std::string data;
std::atomic<bool> ready;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex m;

void producer()
{
    int c{};
    while (true)
    {
        ++c;
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m };
            data = "count: " + std::to_string(c);
            // std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{ 1 }); // THIS LINE
            ready = true;
        }
        cv.notify_one();
    }
}

void consumer()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m };
        cv.wait(lock, []{ return ready == true; });
        std::cout << data << '\n';
        ready = false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread tp{ producer };
    std::thread tc{ consumer };

    tp.join();
    tc.join();
}
```

Comment: What does "does not work as expected" mean? What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead?

Comment: `cv.notify_one()` doesn't block and wait until the other thread wakes up and reacquires the lock. After `cv.notify_one()` call, both threads are racing to lock the mutex. If the producer gets there first, the consumer may observe gaps in the sequence. Is this what you are wondering about?

Comment: Edited to include that info, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each iteration of the `while` loop in the `producer` thread takes a lock, computes `data`, sets `ready=true`, and then unlocks before repeating.

In the case of the sleep statement being uncommented out:

Since the mutex is still held by the OS while `sleep` is invoked, both the producer and consumer thread are effectively paused and are not being given any quantum to run.

Then the sleep statement completes. This enables the producer thread to wake up (with a full quantum). The producer thread, within the quantum time likely is attempting to do the following:

1. set `ready=true`
2. unlocks the mutex as a result of the scope completing
3. invokes `notify_one` to signal the consumer thread that it can get a shot. But keep in mind, the consumer thread is likely paused at this point while the producer thread is running.
4. re-acquire thes lock.

Meanwhile the consumer thread is blocked on the `wait` call. But it eventually gets signaled as available to run when the `notify_one` call is invoked by the producer thread.  Then this likely happens:

The consumer thread will get woken up during step 3 of the producer thread above.  The thread's register state and other stuff will get restored by the OS.  This takes a few cycles. Then it attempts to acquire the lock itself. But by the time it trys to acquire the lock, the producer thread has grabbed it again, because it's already running and not blocked on anything.

Now, I ran your program with the sleep statement uncommented. It will **occassionally** print a `count: XX` line, but rarely. There's a small window in which the consumer thread can "win" the race with the producer thread and acquire the mutex. But it will take many iterations and some luck. In my local repro of building and running your original code with the `sleep` statement uncommented, the program printed this line exactly and nothing else after running for several minutes.

```
count: 41
```

It just happens to work when the sleep statement is commented out because the thread scheduler just happens to occasionally context switch between threads in between unlock and lock calls to the mutex. You might even have different behavior depending on the number of available cores on your system.  As evidence of this, you can see that the `consumer` thread winds up skipping over a bunch of values on each consecutive print call. That's because the producer thread isn't ever blocked on i/o like the consumer thread is with the `cout` and `wait` statements.

```
count: 131
count: 134
count: 2661
count: 2804
count: 2880
...
```

I'm guessing you want to have the consumer thread print each new value assigned to data. If that's the case, unlock the mutex while sleeping.  We can unlock and relock the mutex between sleep statements. But just swapping some lines will suffice:

```
void producer()
{
    int c{};
    while (true)
    {
        ++c;
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m };
            data = "count: " + std::to_string(c);
            ready = true;
        }
        cv.notify_one();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{ 1 });
    }
}
```

This will result in `consumer` printing out each unique value of `data` instead of skipping over any:

```
count: 1
count: 2
count: 3
count: 4
count: 5
count: 6
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand what's going on now.

Comment: What do you mean by "quantum" when you say "... the producer thread is just now resuming with a full quantum. "

Comment: @Jasper1378 - I updated my answer a bit to explain the race condition differences between when `sleep` is commented vs uncommented out. `quantum` is the amount of time a thread is allowed to run before another available thread is scheduled in its place.  The bottom line is that there is a race condition between the producer thread waking up from sleep and the consumer thread waking up again to acquire the lock. But the producer thread is usually waking up first.

Comment: A side effect of all this analysis is that we just proved that the std::mutex doesn't have any fairness to it. That is, a thread can be "waiting" for a mutex.  But the owning thread can give up the mutex and acquire it again without being preempted by any other waiting thread.

Comment: As such, threads can be starved trying to acquire the mutex. There are textbook implementations of mutexes and locks in which a thread can be "next in line" for acquiring a lock when the other thread releases it.  I think your code proves that our implementation of std::mutex doesn't have this. That's probably universal on all platforms.

Comment: @Jasper1378, FYI, "starvation" (as mentioned in selbie's comment, immediately above) is the well-known name of a class of similar problems. A thread is "starved" if it is periodically given opportunities to run, but the synchronized actions of other threads always conspire to make it _miss_ its opportunity most or all of the time.